# Error in line of javascript 'missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass variables to a javascript function but i have the Javascript Error: 'missing ) after argument list"

```html
html = html + '<a href="javascript:initMap2(' + name.lat +','+ name.lng +','+ name.name +');">' + 'Lugar:  ' +name.name +'  Coordenadas: Lat '+ name.lat +'  Lng'+ name.lng+ '</a><br>';
```

It doesn't look like I am missing any ')'s.

Comment: Evaluates to something like `javascript:initMap2(123.456, 45.678, someplace);`, which is invalid (`someplace` is treated as a variable instead of a string). `javascript:initMap2(123.456, 45.678, 'someplace');` is expected here.

Comment: Can you share more of the script?

Comment: And this is why we don't create HTML as concatenated strings...

Comment: If your initMap2 method expects a string in 3rd parameter, then it's not going to get one, as you're not putting quotes around it. Also, if you pass in any undefined values, then it could also break it.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really consider looking into something like React.js or Angular.js to handle your dynamic HTML. It's so much easier and more maintainable/readable.

Comment: Note that there is already a global [*window.name*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property that may not be writeable, so your string may be full of *undefined*.

Comment: Definitely. Rename the `name` variable to be something more meaningful to avoid global clash. The name object has a name property, as well as lat and lng. It would appear to be more meaningful to call it "place" or worldLocation, something like that. Worth a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have found your solution, but here's an alternative anyway, which reduces your string concatenation a little. There's still a far better way of achieving this, but this may help you start to see the benefit of moving away from building HMTL via string concatenation.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<span id="spanTest"></span>
<script>
    // Or whatever your initMap2 function does...
    function initMap2(lat, lng, name) {
        console.log('Lat: ' + lat);
        console.log('Lng: ' + lng);
        console.log('Name: ' + name);
    }

    var spanTest = document.getElementById('spanTest');
    var worldLocation = { name:"test", lat:98.5, lng:-88.45 };
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = 'javascript:initMap2(' + worldLocation.lat +', ' + worldLocation.lng + ', \'' + worldLocation.name + '\');';
    anchor.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + worldLocation.name + ', Lat: ' + worldLocation.lat + ' Lng: ' + worldLocation.lng;
    spanTest.appendChild(anchor);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your last argument is expected to be a string, but it's resolved to look like a variable. Try this instead:

```
html = html + '<a href="javascript:initMap2(' + name.lat +','+ name.lng +',\''+ name.name +'\');">' // etc.
```

When `name.name` resolves to a string, it'll be wrapped in single quotes as expected. It'll look something like `javascript:initMap2(1, 2, 'someString')`.

Comment: @Kevin It "works", but as soon as `name.name` contains an apostrophe, it breaks again. ManoDestra's approach is much more robust.